# Can I travel to the UK as a dependent, after a 10-year ban?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I want to know if I can be granted a visa as a dependent after my 10-year ban has elapsed.

Comment: What do you mean "as a dependent". Do you mean to say you were given a 10 year ban when you were under 8 years of age? Or do you really mean "as a spouse"?

Comment: Has the circumstances that led to the ban been resolved? You can apply, but whether you'll get one is not up to anyone here so we can't answer that, but if the reasons you got banned are still present, chances are higher that an application will attract another ban than be successful. (And why is this tagged "schengen-visas" when it's about the UK? They are not a part of Shengen)

Comment: Being a "dependant" means that somebody else is supporting you. For example if you are a child supported by your parents or a wife supported by your husband.

Comment: @DJClayworth If that comment was to me, I do know that. However, whether the OP was an adult spouse who willing overstayed (assuming that as the reason for the ban) will be treated differently by the deciding officials, than if the OP was a young child who overstayed because their parents did.

Comment: No, that comment was for the OP.

Answer (score 5):

You ask "*can* you" be granted a visa. You've served your time, a 10-year ban, from entry into the UK. There is no longer any reason the UK government, specifically the border agents, for you not be granted the right to enter the UK via a visa.

However, the real question you are probably asking, is *will* you be granted such?

There is absolutely no way for us to know your personal circumstances and your ties to your home country. If you are wealthy enough to be able to afford to travel to and stay in the UK as a tourist, for as long as you are intending, then that check box is handled. The real problem will come when you are attempting to convince the UK agents that you will leave the country at the end of your stay. They will be hard to convince. It also depends on why you were given the ban in the first place.

If your ban was for overstaying, then you've already proven your pre-diposition to ignore the length of visa. If you were banned, as a dependent because your parent or parents overstayed, then by all rights, they should not treat your case as harshly, but you'll need to give even more reasons you have to be willing to return to your home country after. Because you have history that you are attempting to overcome.

In this SE we have had many, very many, people who write questions asking why they were denied a visa with the reason of lack of proof of intention to leave and they didn't have the additional issue you do, which is having already served a ban.